# RESTful API and web navigation - are they compatible?

Tags: html, json, api, rest

Maybe I'm confusing things or over-complicating them, but I'm struggling to develop a RESTful API that supports both HTML and JSON content types. Take for example a simple user management feature. I would expect to have an API that looks like this:

- GET /users: lists all users
- GET /users/{id}: views a single user
- POST /users: creates a new user

A programmatic client posting to /users with a JSON payload would expect a 201 Created response with a Location header specifying the URL to the newly created user, e.g. /users/1. However, a person creating a user through his web browser would post to the same URL with a form-encoded payload and would expect to be redirected to the user list page, requiring the API to return a 302/303 redirect with a Location header of /users.

From a purely conceptual point of view, I find it surprising that an API would react differently based on the submitted content type, and wonder if this is bad design. Then again, maybe it's a mistake to consider the programmatic API and the web-centric API to be the same API and one shouldn't worry about such concerns and worry more about providing a good experience to the different clients.

What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've stumbled upon two separate issues.

One, the typical web browser is a pretty lousy REST client.

Two, web application APIs are not necessarily REST APIs (see #1).

And thus, your conundrum of trying to serve two masters.

Arguably representation has little to do with application semantics when it comes to details such as workflow, particularly if you have equally rich media types (vs a constrained media type such as an image, or something else).

So, in those terms, it's really not appropriate to have the application behave differently given similar media types.

On the other hand, media type IS Yet Another aspect of the request which can influence operation on the back end. You could, for example be requesting an elided "lite" data type that may well not offer links to other parts of the api that a richer media type would, or your authorization level is a factor on what data you can view, as well as what other relations are available, or even what media types are supported at all.

So it's fair that every aspect of the request payload can have impact on the particular semantics and effect of any particular request to the server. In that case, you're scenario is not really off the mark.

In the end, it's down to documentation to clarify your intent as an API designer.